# Powershell - Skip/overwrite the data which is already fetched instead of appending

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, changeset

I am trying to fetch the data in a loop for multiple Build Definition IDs, for each time one Definition ID is called the set of data will be printed, for the next time it should only fetch the data for the Next Build Definition ID and print only that data, I mean it should overwrite the data in a separate file.
But in my case **its appending in a same csv file**

```
param(
[string] $url = 
"https://dev.azure.com/tfs/Projects/<projectname",
[string] $PAT = "<PAT>"
)

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

#Read XML File
[xml]$xmlfile = Get-Content -Path "File.xml" 
$data = $xmlfile | Select-Object - 
Property SkipUpdate, Version | Where-Object{ $_.'SkipUpdate' -eq 'False'}

#Read JSON Data for Starting Changeset and buildDefinitionId
$jsonData = Get-Content "project_configuration.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$branchNames = $jsonData.projectConfig 

#Comparing the data got from XML and JSON and get only the data that we need
$metadata = $branchNames | Select-Object -Property name | Where-Object {$data.Version -eq $_.name}
$metadata.name

#Get the BuildDefinition ID , Start Chnageset and Branch Name of the Version whose SkipUpdate flag is set to False
$alphadata = $branchNames | Where-Object {$data.Version -eq $_.name}
#$alphadata.buildDefinitionId
#$alphadata.startChangeset
#$alphadata.branch
$alphadata | Select-Object -Property buildDefinitionId, startChangeset, branch
$getEndChangesetCall="https://dev.azure.com/tfs/projects/<projectname>_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&statusFilter=completed&resultFilter=succeeded&definitions=<REPLACEBUILDDEFINITIONID>"

foreach($item in $alphadata)
{
$newCall = $getEndChangesetCall.Replace("<REPLACEBUILDDEFINITIONID>", 
$item.buildDefinitionId)
Write-Host "Calling API on $newcall"
$changeset = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $newcall -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header -Verbose
$changeset | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "<path-to-a-file>\ChangesetReq\$($item.builddefinitionId).json"
$changeset.value.sourceVersion[0]                                                                                
#Final API call
$APIUrl= 'https://dev.azure.com/tfs/Projects/<ProjectName>/_apis/tfvc/changesets?searchCriteria.fromId=<FROMCHANGESET>&searchCriteria.toId=<TOCHANGESET>&$orderby=id asc&searchCriteria.itemPath=<PATHFILTER>'
$replaceEntity = $APIUrl.Replace("<FROMCHANGESET>", $item.startChangeset).Replace("<TOCHANGESET>",$changeset.value.sourceVersion[0]).Replace("<PATHFILTER>",$item.branch)
Write-Host "Final API Called on : $replaceEntity"
$reportcall = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $replaceEntity -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header -Verbose

$reportcall | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "<Path-to-the-file>\ChangesetReq\$($item.startChangeset).json"
$reportcall.value | ConvertTo-Json | Out-Null

$reportcall.value | Foreach-Object {
$changesetTfs = $_.changesetId
$authorName = $_.author.displayName
$commentMade = $_.comment
$date = $_.createdDate  
[array] $report += $_.report| ForEach-Object {
            [pscustomobject] @{
            'ChangesetId'= $changesetTfs
            'Author'= $authorName
            'Comments'= $commentMade
            'Date Checked In' = $date 
        } 
                                
    }                  
    
}
Write-Host ($report | Format-Table -Force | Out-String) 

$report | Export-CSV -Path ".\$($item.startChangeset).csv" -NoTypeInformation

}
```

How to overwrite the data/fetch only one particular Definition ID data into a csv file.

Comment: Do you mean `$report | ForEach-Object { $_ | Export-CSV -Path ".\$($_.ChangesetId).csv" -NoTypeInformation }` perhaps?

Comment: @Theo Yeah it works but for a single changesetID it is creating a single csv file, so it will be creating so many files. I need a data for particular Definition ID data into a single csv file.

Comment: Ah, that was not clear to me. Then do `$report | Where-Object { $_.ChangesetId -eq 'TheIDYouAreInterestedIn' } | Export-CSV -Path ".\$($_.ChangesetId).csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: @Theo I have updated the above code, in that `TheIDYouAreInterestedIn` value will come from the **for loop**, so its completely automated that once the script is run for a particular DefinitionID related ChangeSetID details will be printed. Likewise different DefinitionID value should be printed in a separate CSV file. It should not append in a single CSV file as it is in running in the loop.

Comment: You have to move the Export-Csv line out of the loop and below it use `$report | Group-Object ChangesetId | ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Export-CSV -Path ".\$($_.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation }`. Also, better not use `+=` to add to an array. Instead, **remove** `[array] $report += ` and write `$report = $reportcall.value | Foreach-Object {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comments:

If I understand your question correctly now, you can do this to first gather all information in a variable `$report`, then create several groups of that based on the `ChangesetId` and finally save all groups into several CSV files.

```
$report = $reportcall.value | Foreach-Object {
    # output the object to be collected in variable $report
    foreach ($item in $_.report) {
        [pscustomobject] @{
            'ChangesetId'     = $item.changesetId
            'Author'          = $item.author.displayName
            'Comments'        = $item.comment
            'Date Checked In' = $item.createdDate
        } 
    }                  
}

# group the array on property ChangesetId and export the items for each ID separately
$report | Group-Object ChangesetId | ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Group | Export-CSV -Path ".\$($_.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

Comment: Its executing but its not creating any report files as csv. But for that I am not able to see any errors also.

Comment: @Santoshkumar Then, I'm afraid I have no idea what you are trying to achieve,, I gave you three possible solutions but every time this does not seem to be what you expect. If you have no output on this, then probably your variable `$reportcall` is empty or it has no `.value` property. Check on these things first

Comment: Ok sure and thanks alot for all your support.